# How to initiate a Lightning connection

Tags: iphone, lightning, apple

I'm trying to take the first step to establish a connection with an iPhone using the Lightning port. I'm using the Lightning A male connector body, which I believe should set the iPhone to be a USB host. I'm hoping that the iPhone will start to enumerate my USB device, but I'm receiving practically nothing from the phone.

Twice I've seen a short invalid packet of about 16 bits, but that's very rare. What's the first step to take? Do I need some magic pull-up or pull-down somewhere or am I using the wrong connector body? Should I use some other Lightning connector body? I have samples of the four basic types. And yes, I'm an MFi member, hopefully not the only one here.

Comment: Lightning requires an authentication chip. Does you connector have one? If so then maybe you should ask the manufacturer of said chip how it works. The whole point of Lightning is to give Apple control and profit so maybe you should ask them directly.

Comment: Good luck getting the spec from Apple! I suggest if you want to connect a USB device you buy a Lighting to USB adaptor.

Comment: @user1890202, the Lightning authentication chip is included inside all Lightning connectors from Apple. I got the serial one to talk to me by sending the magic init sequence. Now just need to get the usb one working...

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself. It works like standard USB. My mistake was that the phone does not provide VBUS power, only Accessory Power, so the powering, pull-ups, everything was not proper in my test board.